# What are the experiments that established Quantum Field theory beyond the hydrogen atom solution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I took a full undergrad curriculum in physics, got through and understood Quantum Mechanics as taught from an undergraduate level. I've always been curious about what happens "after" though. The development of Quantum Field theory was an important next step in our understanding of physics. In quantum mechanics, the hydrogen atom spectrum was key experimental evidence that confirmed the theory. Is there an experiment or set of experiments that does the same for Quantum Field theory and beyond?

Comment: Every experiment performed at particle accelerators around the world (for a list, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accelerators_in_particle_physics) is one that does the same for quantum field theory. So far none of the experiments have gone beyond the regime of quantum field theory though.

Comment: Historically speaking, the Lamb shift (Bethe) and the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron (Schwinger). Perhaps also the Einstein coefficients (Dirac).

Comment: This is a good question and deserves a full answer. @Accidental Fourier Transform's comment could be an answer with a little more detail.

Comment: Since you asked me below, landmarks of QFT are better discussed in the [suitable SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantum+field+theory).

Comment: The Casimir effect is sometimes seen as strong evidence of QFT.

Answer (score -1):

This is an experimentalist's view, take it as a long comment:

As doing experiments in particle physics since 1970 , I can guarantee that all data were fitted with quantum field theory models. The history is long and step wise, and there is a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quantum_field_theory#Early_developments) article on it.

> I took a full undergrad curriculum in physics, got through and understood Quantum Mechanics as taught from an undergraduate level. I've always been curious about what happens "after" though.

The following is to update your quantum mechanical background with respect to quantum field theory:

Quantum mechanics is all one framework, with given [postulates and principles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html), which pick up the solutions of differential wave equations which describe and predict the data in the microcosm ( and not only, there is superconductivity which goes for miles). Within this framework the simple wave functions, Dirac, Klein Gordon, quantized Maxwell, (the Schrodinger is not relativistic , so not good for high energies) describe two body bound  potential interactions very well , giving energy levels that fit the data. Scatterings and decays were a problem.

Also, once one goes to many bodies, it is not possible in general to create potentials to be inserted into the differential equations and get exact solutions for the wavefunction. Instead, quantum field theory was invented, which is a way of expanding into a series the solutions needed for a specific problem, as electron positron  scattering, for example, at high energies, with creation of many particles.

Quantum field theory for the [standard model of elementary particles,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) posits that each elementary particle in the table for all (x,y,z,t) exist as an operator  [*field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)#Field_theory) , this consists of the plane wave  solution  for the corresponding particle ( electron: dirac with zero potential for example) and  differential creation and annihilation operators on this field generating or destroying a particle ( an electron). This is illustrated in the [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html), which have a prescription for expanding into a series the needed solution, the first order terms dominant.

Thus quantum field theory is a sophisticated mathematical model , utilizing   the plane wave  solutions of the basic quantum mechanical equations to extend calculational possibilities for decays, scatterings and many body problems.

[image: ee]

An example of e- e- scattering which evaluated ,successfully fits e-e- scattering.

(Real particles, as plane waves are not localized , [wave packets](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html)have to be  used to model them.)

Comment: -1 You did not list and describe any experiments, just a link to wikipedia. Ironic since you claim to work in the field.

Comment: @user157879  the list of experiments in particl physics are th0usands. I did not delve into the history because it is a developement,, not an "aha " discovery, as you would see if you read the history. And in any case, I said to take it as a long comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @user157879  The link to wikipedia *has* the "crucial" key to the question: QFT is the language of dealing with particle species creation and annihilation, so, then mutation. ***Every*** high energy physics experiment where species are created is always thought of in terms of relativistic QFT... So starting in the particle zoo explosion of the 50s and 60s, and on to the SM, ***all experiments*** made sense in terms of QFT, in increasing circles of agreement. Listing all HEP experiments to "establish QFT" hardly makes sense.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, you could say the exact same thing for literally any branch of physics. The point is not to list all of them, but to choose a few key ones to discuss with particular historical importance (i.e. Lamb shift, etc.).

Comment: You must have misread the history of QFT on the link. It has been the other way round. QFT "explained" β-decay by setting the framework for it. No one experiment clinched it. The Lamb shift preceded and only validated a *technique* of QFT.  All of HEP in the 50s - 70s relied on QFT. The only "smoking gun" validation of QFT was the discovery of neutral currents validating the Weinberg model. In most other cases, as already emphasized, progress was incremental and tentative. Only bad popular science books and TV programs can argue to the contrary. Look at the Pais book to appreciate the point.

Comment: Link to the [Pais book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400620/recommendations-for-a-book-that-compiles-how-the-theory-mathematical-equipment/400675#400675).   Progress in QFT has been driven by theory. Its link and utility to experiment, as this answer reviews has been   established since Fermi: relativity, particle mutation and indefinite numbers of particles virtually "established" it as the  obvious theory linked to HEP. Unlike QM, it never had to compete with and beat classical models.

Comment: @CosmasZachos if there was not a "smoking gun" validating QFT, then what motivated it??

Comment: @CosmasZachos is there a better question I could have asked to get an understanding of the historical development of QFT?

Comment: @MikeFlynn Readers struggle with your expectation of an answer that  a few  key experiments  somehow led to QFT.  As the WP article indicates this   hardly ever happened. There were a plethora of experimental facts that QFT explained increasingly better with increasing refinements. Neutral currents were searched in the abstract, to see if they were around, *not* out of excessive curiosity about the validity Weinberg's QFT-based model. That model was designed to explain the well-known massive WI intermediators and the mass of chiral fermions involved in it.

Comment: A better, but impossibly broad question would be about key advances of QFT--if they were advances, of course they comported with experimental facts. My sense is reading the WP article and Pais might inspire narrower more focussed questions.